# React "static" component, set state from any compoent

Tags: reactjs, components

I hav an (medium sized) react app which loads data from different components. Now i want to show an error message in the bottom left of the screen. I want only one field there which I can set to some text. The problem is I want to set the field from different components, somewhere on the page. So I want some sort of "static" component which I instantiate once high up in the applications hirachy and then manipulate its state with a simple function call from anywhere. Something like this:

````
<ErrorMessageHolder></ErrorMessageHolder>
<SomeOtherComponent></SomeOtherComponent>
```

SomeOtherComponent or a component inside SomeOtherComponent calls a js function defined somewhere and sets some variable, which the ErrorMessageHolder uses to update the displayed text.

I tried using contexts but I would need to pass the variable up the hiracy to the place where teh context is defined through callbacks in order to change it.
````

Comment: You can use "useContext" which will set the value of error message and than - call that state value from that context. Please share your code on codesandbox, so I can look into it and help you out.

Comment: Or you can introduce a global state and push data to it on errors. Your notification component then can subscribe to that field.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
export const ERROR_EVENT_NAME = "pageerror";

/**
 * The event detail of an error event.
 */
export interface ErrorEventDetails {
    /**
     * The error message.
     */
    msg: string;
}

/**
 * Fire a "pageerror" event.
 * @param details The error details.
 */
export function fireError(detail: ErrorEventDetails) {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(ERROR_EVENT_NAME, { detail }));
}
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ERROR_EVENT_NAME, ErrorEventDetails } from "./ErrorEvent";

/**
 * The applicaitons error box which displays "pageerror"s.
 * Should only be loaded once.
 */
export function ErrorBox() {
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const listener: any = (e: CustomEvent<ErrorEventDetails>) => {
            setMsg(e.detail.msg);
        };

        document.addEventListener(ERROR_EVENT_NAME, listener);
        return () => document.removeEventListener(ERROR_EVENT_NAME, listener);
    });

    return <p className="text-red-600">{msg}</p>;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).